# Android distribution to intercept HTTPS traffic

Tags: android, proxy, ssl, https, inspection

Since Android 11, intercepting HTTPS traffic has become more difficult (still possible but requires many more steps).

Is there a maintained Android distribution that makes it easy?

- It should by default have a root CA certificate whose secret I can access.
- Ideally it would come with a UI to select apps, and see/record passing packets as an overlay, similar to [HttpCanary](https://m.apkpure.com/httpcanary-%E2%80%94-http-sniffer-capture-analysis/com.guoshi.httpcanary).
- Either GSI or ROM, ideally installable on recent Pixel devices.

Using an old Android distribution would be possible, but it would be insecure.

Comment: So you are searching for an generic System Image (GSI) or do you search for a custom ROM? If it is the latter you need a matching ROM for your device model. I don't know a GSI or ROM dedicated for network analysis. Most people just perform the necessary steps (Magisk + Magisk move certificates module). If you need to bypass certificate pinning then you need Frida + a script matching the app.